# wordpress nonadmin media file upload thumbnail refresh error

Tags: wordpress, image-uploading, mod-security

I am trying to upload media image file from non admin user.The file is getting uploaded successfully. But when it uploads and refreshes thumbnail media view. it gives error "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."
I have given the nonadmin user role capabilities to upload_files, edit_pages,  edit_post, read_post,read_pages for the non-admin user.
Also tried adding following in .htaccess file as per this post http://wordpress.org/support/topic/upload-error-5

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

and also tried adding the said code in wp-config.php file as said here http://classforbeginner.blogspot.in/2013/04/wordpress-image-upload-error.html
but no lock its giving same error and does not show thumbnail of image just after auto refresh, but files gets uploaded.

but when you load media library again it shows the uploaded file and image can be used in post.

thanks for any suggestions/solutions in advance

Comment: :( no replies yet... google search gave one of solution as disable plugins & try or reinstall wordpress from dashboard admin.

Answer (score 0):

This error tends to indicate a malformed response from the server. Try disabling any active plugins, then if that doesn't work, I'd try writing an HTML form that mocks the javascript upload parameters. Examining the response may help - it should be valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am newbie to wordpress. I didnt get you, like what has to be tried. I tried to check json response from aync-upload.php. it gives me all homepage html script instead of giving array of images from gallery folder. its probably because of new user role (dummy of administrator with admin capabilities) which i have logged in & trying to upload file.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `/wp-content/uploads` folder has 777 permission. You have to apply the permission to all the folders under this folder. I know 777 is a very insecure permission. But, I would ask other to enlighten on it, because I always had to enable this permission for the uploads folder.

The `mod-security` and other things as plugin enable/disable dont seem to be an issue here. Let me know what happens.